# Obtener Checkbox checked desde base de datos en un arrray json en laravel

Tags: laravel, json, array, checkbox

Necesito marcar mis checkbox en la mi view de laravel de acuerdo a los valores guardados

```
type_work
-------------
["Fotografia","Escultura","Pintura"]
```

Estos son mi valores almacenados en un registro anterior del mismo artista

Este es mi controller

```
$type_work = Artista::select('type_work')->get();

return view('perfil.index',compact('type_work'));
```

Esta es mi view

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type_work[]" 
     @foreach($type_work as $item)      
       @foreach(json_decode($item) as $itm)
         {{ $itm == "Fotografia" ? "checked" : "" }}
           @endforeach
      @endforeach> Fotografia
```

Pero no se me marcan, alguna idea?

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso también me llegó a pasar a mí, en vez de usar operadores ternarios, usa el `@if`.

Además está algo raro cómo implementas tus checkboxes, ni tampoco por qué usas `json_decode` si no tienes un JSON, no hay necesidad de tenerlo así.

El método `get()` te devuelve una colección de elementos de esa clase. Lo que te devuelve únicamente es un una colección de esta forma:

```js
[ 
  App\Artista {
   type_work: "Fotografia",
  },
  App\Artista {
   type_work: "Escultura",
  }
]
```

Está es la forma en la que yo lo haría:

```html
@foreach($artists as $artist)      
 @if($artist->type_work == "Fotografia")
 <input type="checkbox" name="type_work" value="Fotografia" checked>
 @else
 <input type="checkbox" name="type_work" value="value">
 @endif
@endforeach>
```

Ahora, si los artistas pueden tener más de un tipo de trabajo y las relaciones entre los modelos están bien hechas. Solamente sería un foreach anidado y poner un name como value

```html
@foreach($artists as $artist)  
 @foreach($artist->type_work as $type)
   @if($artist->type_work == "Fotografia")
   <input type="checkbox" name="type_work" value="Fotografia" checked>
   @else
   <input type="checkbox" name="type_work" value="value">
   @endif
 @ednforeach
@endforeach>
```

Comment: Me sirivio muchisimo, gracias :D

Comment: De nada, considera votar arriba por mi respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

A manera de ayuda para otros usuarios agrego una solucion alternativa teniendo en cuenta que estos valores del array o json son traidos desde la base de datos o un archivo JSON.

```
@foreach ($type_work as $id => $name)
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input name="type_work[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $name }}"
                {{ $model->type_work->contains($id) || collect (old('type_work') )->contains($name) ? 'checked' : '' }} > // Donde el model es el parametro que pasamos desde una vista BLADE usando @include (sabiendo que se usa para crear o para editar)
            {{ $name }}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Devolviendo este array desde un controlador con

```
$type_work = TypeWork::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Con esto se crearan los checkboxes necesarios para hacer check en alguno siempre y cuando se alla creado previamente el registro